# spring-security-crypto jar is not getting updated in ./m2/repository/

Tags: spring, spring-security

While changing Spring-security version in my projects maven file, from **3.1.0.RELEASE** to **4.2.4.RELEASE**, my './m2/repository/...' does not seem to downloading spring-security-crypto.4.2.4.RELEASE jar.
Though I have declared in my dependencies the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I used the following build command

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Build is successful, but crypto jar is not getting downloaded. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If Maven build is completed without any errors, it means this just was found, but you are looking in the wrong directory.

1. May be you are using other user name and that's why the ".m2" is in the other user home folder.
2. May be you have specified Maven repository path in .m2/setting.xml, which is not .m2/repository.
3. May be you are looking in the wrong directory below .m2/repository.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions! The problem with my firewall, which was blocking to download this 'crypto' jar from internet. But strangely, I did not get any error about failure of this download. I am not sure if this because this jar was not needed in my code, though I have mentioned in dependency (??)

Comment: The problem is- when I declare dependency for **spring-security-web.3.1.0.RELEASE**, it downloads security jars, and also **spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE** on its own. Though, I don't declare dependency for 'spring-security-crypto', still it gets downloaded by  'spring-security-web.3.1.0.RELEASE'.

Comment: But, When I change version to **spring-security-web.4.2.4.RELEASE**, it does not download spring-security-crypto.
Does it mean that crypto is already included on spring-security-web.4.2.4.RELEASE version & hence it does not download 'crypto' explicitly, just opposite to what it does in case of 3.1.0.RELEASE ?   Please suggest.

Comment: In Spring 3 there was a dependecy spring-security-web --> spring-security-core --> spring-security-crypto. In Spring 4 there is no dependency spring-security-core --> spring-security-crypto. That's why you don't retrieve spring-security-crypto. If you need it, just add it to the dependencies. If you need some library, define such dependency EXPLICITY. It is error prone to expect that the library you need will be retrieved via some other dependency.

Comment: I have defined the spring-security-crypto dependency explicitly:-

Comment: I have defined spring-security-crypto dependency explicitly in my POM file:-  **<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>**            but it is still not getting downloaded. I see all other security jars(core, config, taglibs, web, acl) are getting downloaded at this location : "C:\Users\usrName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\*"  Any thought. I have searched everywhere in my computer.

Comment: There is no magic. You say the build is successful. It means the dependency WAS downloaded and you are looking in the wrong directory. It is easy to check. Delete your local repository and launch the build again. If it is successful, it means you are using repository in some other directory.

Comment: Here is the reason, why it is not downloading crypto jar excliplicitly and still build is successful:- spring-security-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar is having the crypto packages under it, which contains crypto jars. like : org.springframework.security.crypto.codec and all.

Comment: So now I am excluding the cryoto in dependency as follows :    **<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
     <!-- Exclude crypto -->
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency> **  But the  **exclusion** is not working because I see, the core still downloads crypto inside it.  How to exclude crypto from Core ??